# How to convert BLOB object to PL Json

Tags: json, oracle, image, blob, clob

i am using below code to load image file from server to BLOB Object

but after convert it to clob and put it into json it reformatted. 
how can i fix this

```
FUNCTION get_person_image(v_file_name varchar2) RETURN json AS
 tmp_blob    blob default EMPTY_BLOB();
 tmp_bfile   bfile := null;
 dest_offset integer := 1;
 src_offset  integer := 1;
 v_ret_json  json := json();
BEGIN
 tmp_bfile   := BFILENAME('PICTURES', v_file_name);
 DBMS_LOB.OPEN(tmp_bfile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
 DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(tmp_blob, TRUE);
 DBMS_LOB.LOADBLOBFROMFILE(tmp_blob,
                          tmp_bfile,
                          DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE,
                          dest_offset,
                          src_offset);
 DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(tmp_bfile);
 v_ret_json.put('name', v_file_name);
 v_ret_json.put('image', blob_to_clob(tmp_blob));

 RETURN v_ret_json;

END get_person_image;

FUNCTION blob_to_clob(blob_in IN BLOB) RETURN CLOB AS
 v_clob    CLOB;
 v_varchar VARCHAR2(32767);
 v_start   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
 v_buffer  PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
begin
 DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_clob, TRUE);

 FOR i IN 1 .. CEIL(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_in) / v_buffer) LOOP

  v_varchar := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(blob_in,
                                                        v_buffer,
                                                        v_start));

  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(v_clob, LENGTH(v_varchar), v_varchar);
  v_start := v_start + v_buffer;
 END LOOP;
 RETURN v_clob;
END blob_to_clob;
```

Once the get_person_image read image file the CLOB Contains data like below HEX:
00 01 00 00 FF DB 00 84  00 09 06 07 13 13 12 15
13 12 13 15 16 15 15 18  1D 17 17 16 18 17 17 16
18 18 17 18 1A 18 18 17  18 17 18 18 1D 28 20 1A
1A 25 1B 18 17 22 31 21  25 29 2B 2E 2E 2E 17 20
33 38 33 2C 37 28 2D 2E  2B 01 0A 0A 0A 0E 0D 0E
1B 10 10 1B 2D 25 20 25  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D
2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D  2D 2D 2F 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D
2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D
2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D  2D 2D FF C0 00 11 08 01
0F 00 BA 03 01 22 00 02  11 01 03 11 01 FF C4 00
1C 00 00 01 05 01 01 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 05 00 03 04 06 07  02 01 08 FF C4 00 43 10
00 01 02 03 05 05 06 03  07 02 05 02 07 00 00 00
01 02 11 00 03 21 04 05  12 31 41 06 51 61 71 91
22 32 81 A1 B1 F0 13 C1  D1 14 23 42 52 62 82 E1
07 72 15 92 A2 B2 F1 33  C2 16 24 43 63 74 B3 F3
FF C4 00 18 01 00 03 01  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02  03 04 FF C4 00 21 11 01
01 00 03 01 01 01 01 01  00 03 01 00 00 00 00 00
01 02 11 21 31 41 03 12  22 42 51 81 32 FF DA 00
0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11  00 3F 00 DB A3 89 B3 00
04 9A 01 1E A9 4D 19 8E  DF 6D 62 D4 A3 67 B3 BD
28 A5 0D FB 9F D7 FE 61  5B A3 93 69 3B 5F B7 69
41 32 E4 76 D4 EC 5B 2E  35 1E 9C 6B BA 33 F9 B6
D5 AD 41 53 89 5A F4 4E  89 F9 0F 7C E2 39 93 84
BB E2 51 A5 32 F3 88 76  89 85 CA 52 5B F3 1E 3A
87 FA C4 5B B6 D2 69 2E  D7 7B 2A A1 FA 51 23 A6
71 09 53 54 4E A4 EF 67  3E 03 21 E3 0A 4A 10 1A
98 BA 81 EB E6 63 A5 CF  03 26 E6 3D E5 EF 93 93
45 6E CC AA C4 09 FB C5  37 E9 15 5F 5C 93 E0 22
44 A4 24 1F BB 96 90 77  9E D2 FC E2 32 2D 6F 90
61 F9 8D 49 E5 BA 1C 33  30 A5 CD 3A 97 30 C9 39
04 20 E2 99 32 BB 80 0F  D6 24 D9 2F 79 45 60 09
20 F1 38 49 26 9A AA 83  C6 2B 33 A6 13 5C 87 31
EB 1D D8 E8 71 00 4B 74  FE 7C 61 06 AB 79 4A 49
97 2F EE A5 8C 75 0A 49  ED 00 CC A0 A3 91 0C 68
74 2D 1D DD 56 F9 72 08  29 99 50 18 B1 A1 6A 54
0A 13 C7 D2 33 4B 55 F4  65 E6 5D 67 47 A2 79 EF
3E F9 C0 5D ED 31 59 13  E8 3A 6B 07 A3 91 F4 75
DB 7B 95 80 42 82 81 19  1A 1C B4 3A C1 8B 35 A9
2B 1D 93 96 63 50 63 06  D9 CB DE 6C 89 92 E6 29
01 68 52 80 51 72 0A 08  EC F6 AA 03 38 53 BB D2
B5 70 0D D6 6D F2 A9 33  5E 59 55 49 39 12 4A 58
66 06 7A D2 1E F4 5F CE  DA 58 8F 60 3D C5 7F 4A
B4 20 29 2A 0F AB 1D 60  BB C5 22 CD 3D 85 0A 14
04 50 A1 42 80 14 28 50  A0 05 0A 14 28 02 AF B6
D7 DF D9 E4 16 3D B5 F6  53 F3 57 24 FA B4 63 CA
99 53 9B E6 B5 1F 24 8E  3E F9 17 DB 5B EC CF
.....
and when i open as text in PLSQL it is something like this :

���JFIF

after v_ret_json.put('image', blob_to_clob(tmp_blob)); it reformatted as :

Hex View :

7B 0D 0A 20 20 22 6E 61  6D 65 22 20 3A 20 22 34
31 32 2E 70 6E 67 22 2C  0D 0A 20 20 22 69 6D 61
67 65 22 20 3A 20 22 5C  75 46 46 46 44 5C 75 46
46 46 44 5C 75 46 46 46  44 4A 46 49 46 5C 75 30
30 30 30 5C 75 30 30 30  31 5C 75 30 30 30 31 5C
75 30 30 30 30 5C 75 30  30 30 30 5C 75 30 30 30
31 5C 75 30 30 30 30 5C  75 30 30 30 31 5C 75 30
30 30 30 5C 75 30 30 30  30 5C 75 46 46 46 44 5C
75 46 46 46 44 5C 75 46  46 46 44 5C 75 30 30 30
30 5C 74 5C 75 30 30 30  36 5C 75 30 30 30 37 5C
75 30 30 31 33 5C 75 30  30 31 33 5C 75 30 30 31
32 5C 75 30 30 31 35 5C  75 30 30 31 33 5C 75 30
30 31 32 5C 75 30 30 31  33 5C 75 30 30 31 35 5C
75 30 30 31 36 5C 75 30  30 31 35 5C 75 30 30 31
35 5C 75 30 30 31 38 5C  75 30 30 31 44 5C 75 30
30 31 37 5C 75 30 30 31  37 5C 75 30 30 31 36 5C
75 30 30 31 38 5C 75 30  30 31 37 5C 75 30 30 31
37 5C 75 30 30 31 36 5C  75 30 30 31 38 5C 75 30
30 31 38 5C 75 30 30 31  37 5C 75 30 30 31 38 5C
75 30 30 31 41 5C 75 30  30 31 38 5C 75 30 30 31
38 5C 75 30 30 31 37 5C  75 30 30 31 38 5C 75 30
30 31 37 5C 75 30 30 31  38 5C 75 30 30 31 38 5C
75 30 30 31 44 28 20 5C  75 30 30 31 41 5C 75 30
30 31 41 25 5C 75 30 30  31 42 5C 75 30 30 31 38
5C 75 30 30 31 37 5C 22  31 21 25 29 2B 2E 2E 2E
5C 75 30 30 31 37 20 33  38 33 2C 37 28 2D 2E 2B
5C 75 30 30 30 31 5C 6E  5C 6E 5C 6E 5C 75 30 30
30 45 5C 72 5C 75 30 30  30 45 5C 75 30 30 31 42
5C 75 30 30 31 30 5C 75  30 30 31 30 5C 75 30 30
31 42 2D 25 20 25 2D 2D  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D
2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D  2F 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D
2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D
2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D  5C 75 46 46 46 44 5C 75
46 46 46 44 5C 75 30 30  30 30 5C 75 30 30 31 31
5C 62 5C 75 30 30 30 31  5C 75 30 30 30 46 5C 75
30 30 30 30 5C 75 46 46  46 44 5C 75 30 30 30 33
5C 75 30 30 30 31 5C 22  5C 75 30 30 30 30 5C 75
30 30 30 32 5C 75 30 30  31 31 5C 75 30 30 30 31
5C 75 30 30 30 33 5C 75  30 30 31 31 5C 75 30 30
30 31 5C 75 46 46 46 44  5C 75 46 46 46 44 5C 75
30 30 31 43 5C 75 30 30  30 30 5C 75 30 30 30 30
5C 75 30 30 30 31 5C 75  30 30 30 35 5C 75 30 30
30 31 5C 75 30 30 30 31  5C 75 30 30 30 31 5C 75
30 30 30 30 5C 75 30 30  30 30 5C 75 30 30 30 30
5C 75 30 30 30 30 5C 75  30 30 30 30 5C 75 30 30
30 30 5C 75 30 30 30 30  5C 75 30 30 30 30 5C 75
30 30 30 30 5C 75 30 30  30 30 5C 75 30 30 30 35
5C 75 30 30 30 30 5C 75  30 30 30 33 5C 75 30 30

Text View :

"name" : "412.png",
  "image" : "\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFDJFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0000\t\u0006\u0007\u0013\u0013\u0012\u0015\u0013\u0012\u0013\u0015\u0016\u0015\u0015\u0018\u001D\u0017\u0017\u0016\u0018\u0017\u0017\u0016\u0018\u0018\u0017\u0018\u001A\u0018\u0018\u0017\u0018\u0017\u0018\u0018\u001D( \u001A\u001A%\u001B\u0018\u0017\"1!%)+...\u0017 383,7(-.+\u0001\n\n\n\u000E\r\u000E\u001B\u0010\u0010\u001B-% %------------------/-------------------------------\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0000\u0011\b\u0001\u000F\u0000\uFFFD\u0003\u0001\"\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0001\u0003\u0011\u0001\uFFFD\uFFFD\u001C\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0000\u0003\u0004\u0006\u0007\u0002\u0001\b\uFFFD\uFFFDC\u0010\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0005\u0005\u0006\u0003\u0007\u0002\u0005\u0002\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0011\u0000\u0003!\u0004\u0005\u00121A\u0006Qaq\uFFFD\"2\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0014#BRb\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0015\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD$Cct\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0018\u0001\u0000\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\uFFFD\uFFFD!\u0011\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0011!1A\u0003\u0012\"BQ\uFFFD2\uFFFD\uFFFD\f\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0003\u0011\u0000?\u0000\u06E3\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0000\u0004\uFFFD\u0001\u001E\uFFFDM\u0019\uFFFD\uFFFDb\u0523g\uFFFD\uFFFD(\uFFFD\r\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFDa[\uFFFD\uFFFDi;_\uFFFDiA2\uFFFD\uFFFD5\u001E\uFFFDk\uFFFD3\uFFFD\uFFFD\u056DAS\uFFFDZ\uFFFD\u000F|\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD2\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD[\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD.\uFFFD*\uFFFD\uFFFDQ#\uFFFDq\tSTN\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0003!\uFFFD\u0010\u001A\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD&\uFFFD\uF4D3En\u032A

Comment: What do you mean,"it reformatted"?  Please provide complete details.

Comment: i will provide the info in my question, will edit it

Comment: i updated the question, and add the details of output my functions, any update in this regard ?